# Two lines for x-axis label with different font sizes in R grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a grouped bar chart where X-axis contains Employee types e.g. Staff, Teacher etc. and I put the label for each group like following
[image]

I would like to put the numbers below each group inside parenthesis and make the font size smaller. This is what I tried so far

```
data <- read.csv("Emp.txt", sep = "\t" , header = TRUE)
df1<-tibble(data)
df1<- mutate(df1, emp_class = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 52, 75), 
                                  labels = c('(0-19)', '(20-22)', '(23-25)', '(26-28)', '(29-31)', '(32-34)', '(35-52)', '(53-75)'))) 

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Emp_group) %>% 
  add_count() 

df1 <- mutate(df1, x_axis = paste(Emp_group, n, sep = "\n"))
my_ggp <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(x_axis), fill=as.factor(emp_class)))+
  geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]*100), position="dodge") + ylab('% Employes') +xlab("") + labs(fill = "Age group") 
df1
my_ggp + theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good way to apply different formats to a single axis label text. To get the raw count on a line below the axis label is relatively straightforward, though. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat <- mtcars %>%
    count(cyl, carb) %>%
    mutate(across(c(cyl, carb), ~ as.factor(.))) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(n))

dat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = n, fill = carb)) +
        geom_col(position = "dodge") +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = function(cyl) {
            total <- unique(pull(filter(dat, cyl == cyl), total))
            paste0(cyl, "\n (n = ", total, ")")
        })
```

The idea is to use a function in `scale_x_discrete` (or whatever `scale_x_...` type your data is). The function takes in breaks, which in this example would be `c(4, 6, 8)`, and with your data would be `c("Custodian", "Staff", "Teacher")`. You then use that to find the totals value (I've shown one way, there are lots of alternatives). Finally, you construct your axis label with `paste`, and use "\n" to specify the new line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks !! it looks cleaner than what I was doing. Yes, it seems that it is better to edit the text after plotting the chart

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark as accepted if it answers the question.